# Delphi check if character is in range 'A'..'Z' and '0'..'9'

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, range

I need to check if a string contains only characters from ranges: `'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '0'..'9'`, so I wrote this function:

```
function GetValueTrat(aValue: string): string;
const
  number = [0 .. 9];
const
  letter = ['a' .. 'z', 'A' .. 'Z'];
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  for i := 1 to length(aValue) do
  begin
    if (not(StrToInt(aValue[i]) in number)) or (not(aValue[i] in letter)) then
      raise Exception.Create('Non valido');
  end;

  Result := aValue.Trim;
end;
```

but if for example, `aValue = 'Hello'` the `StrToInt` function raise me an Exception.

Comment: Why not using http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsLetterOrDigit

Comment: Because I've got either letters and numbers

Comment: @img.simone Letters or numbers: Thats exactly what the linked function does.

Comment: I realise you have accepted an answer, but for future reference, the terms in your if tests are the wrong way around.  Calling StrToInt will fail with an exception if aValue[i] is a letter, so you should test that first and only call StrToInt if the letter test fails.  But, as you have seen, there is no need to check for digits by using StrToInt in the first place.

Comment: @RBA - you function is different. It may be better or worse than TS's request, but it gives different results. For example consider non-Latin letters in Spanish or French or German alphabets.

Comment: What if you just catch the exception and show an appropriate message o the user? A raised exception not means the end of the world.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An unique set of `Char` can be used for your purpose.

```
function GetValueTrat(const aValue: string): string;
const
  CHARS = ['0'..'9', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := aValue.Trim;
  for i := 1 to Length(Result) do
  begin
    if not (Result[i] in CHARS) then
      raise Exception.Create('Non valido');
  end;
end;
```

Notice that in your function if `aValue` contains a space character - like `'test value '` for example - an exception is raised so the usage of `Trim` is useless after the `if` statement.

---

A regular expression like `^[0-9a-zA-Z]` can solve your issue in a more elegant way in my opinion.

---

**EDIT**
According to the [@RBA's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938803/delphi-check-if-character-is-in-range-a-z-and-0-9#comment61436974_36938803) to the question, [System.Character.TCharHelper.IsLetterOrDigit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.IsLetterOrDigit) can be used as a replacement for the above logic:

```
if not Result[i].IsLetterOrDigit then
  raise Exception.Create('Non valido');
```

Comment: 1) it is not a good code since Delphi 2009 - compiler would give a warning here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.CharInSet
 / / / / / 
2) no, RBA is wrong here: the function the pointed is different than what topic-starter asked. TS wanted only Latin letters and RBA flagged all the letters of all the alphabets

Comment: @Arioch'The - You are correct. I've pointed that function assuming that the OP does not care about unicode(based on the code existing in the question).